# CMSIS code inline asm use ldr instruction with .w suffix error

Tags: assembly, arm

when i porting CMSIS_NN code on my stm32h750 project , *arm_depthwise_separable_conv_HWC_q7_nonsquare* functions has inline asm for speed up process :

```
                __asm volatile("COL_LOOP%=:\n"
                         "ldr.w r2, [%[pB], #0]\n"
                         "add.w %[pB], %[pB], %[ch_im_in]\n"
                         "ldr.w r5, [%[pB], #0]\n"
                         "add.w %[pB], %[pB], %[ch_im_in]\n"
                         "pkhtb r3, r5, r2, ASR #16\n"
                         "pkhbt r2, r2, r5, LSL #16\n"
                         "ldr.w r0, [%[pA], #0]\n"
                         "add.w %[pA], %[pA], %[ch_im_in]\n"
                         "ldr.w r5, [%[pA], #0]\n"
                         "add.w %[pA], %[pA], %[ch_im_in]\n"
                         "pkhtb r1, r5, r0, ASR #16\n"
                         "pkhbt r0, r0, r5, LSL #16\n"
                         "sxtb16 r4, r0\n"
                         "sxtb16 r5, r2\n"
                         "smlad %[sum], r4, r5, %[sum]\n"
                         "mov.w r4, r0, ror #8\n"
                         "mov.w r5, r2, ror #8\n"
                         "sxtb16 r4, r4\n"
                         "sxtb16 r5, r5\n"
                         "smlad %[sum2], r4, r5, %[sum2]\n"
                         "sxtb16 r4, r1\n"
                         "sxtb16 r5, r3\n"
                         "smlad %[sum3], r4, r5, %[sum3]\n"
                         "mov.w r4, r1, ror #8\n"
                         "mov.w r5, r3, ror #8\n"
                         "sxtb16 r4, r4\n"
                         "sxtb16 r5, r5\n"
                         "smlad %[sum4], r4, r5, %[sum4]\n"
                         "subs %[colCnt], #1\n"
                         "bne COL_LOOP%=\n"
                         : [ sum ] "+r"(sum),
                           [ sum2 ] "+r"(sum2),
                           [ sum3 ] "+r"(sum3),
                           [ sum4 ] "+r"(sum4),
                           [ pB ] "+r"(pB),
                           [ pA ] "+r"(pA)
                         : [ colCnt ] "r"(colCnt), [ ch_im_in ] "r"(ch_im_in)
                         : "r0", "r1", "r2", "r3", "r4", "r5");
```

i use AC6.14 compiler build codes.and error occurs :

```
CMSIS_BASE/arm_nn_q.c(2537): error: too many operands for instruction
"ldr.w r4, [%[pA]], #4\n"

<inline asm>(2): note: instantiated into assembly here
ldr.w r4, [r12], #4

CMSIS_BASE/arm_nn_q.c(2538): error: too many operands for instruction
                 "ldr.w r1, [%[pB]], #8\n"
                  ^
   <inline asm>(3): note: instantiated into assembly here
   ldr.w r1, [lr], #8
```

i found all error were about ldr.w instruction.
when i remove .w suffix the error is disappear. i don't know why ARM release ldr.w replace ldr ,on the ARMV7M manual ldr is equal to ldr.w。

Comment: That means use the "wide" Thumb2 encoding.  IDK why the'd specify that manually instead of letting the assembler figure out how to encode.

Comment: This isn't connected to the .w suffix.  It is complaining about the offset being outside the square brackets, which IIRC means post-increment the pointer register.

This is a thumb2 extension to the thumb instruction set.  I suspect that you have the compiler build target set incorrectly.

If it is set correctly then this is either a bug in the compiler or the CMSIS.

Comment: @TomV  i have correct  `ldr.w r4, [%[pA]], #4`  to `ldr.w r4, [%[pA] , #4]` ,and the compiler error is turn to CMSIS_BASE/arm_nn_q.c(2544): error: register expected
                     "ldr.w r3, [%[pB], -#4]\n"    but when i get rid of .w suffix , the code can be build with no error. and i will test them .

Comment: @OrangeTeam These two instructions do different things.  You cannot replace one with the other.  I strongly recommend you to ditch this code if you don't understand enough assembly to maintain it.  Also, this use of inline assembly is really terrible and should be avoided.  The compiler can probably generate way better code from just C code or C code with individual inline asm statements, as opposed to this huge block you have.

Comment: If it builds correctly without the .w and with the 4 back outside the bracket then you have solved the problem.  You can't move the 4, that changes the meaning.

Comment: @fuz  you are right , after replace ,the code run HARDFAULT.   I'll just use Intrinsic C.